# Chosen.js not working for multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have the following sample code.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a country..." multiple class="chosen-select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.css" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
</script>
```

Which results in the following picture. Any insights into why this wouldn't be working? I've tried it in Chrome and IE, for reference. The console says 'chosen is not a function'.

[image]

**Update:**

Got it. If you're using Asp.net make sure your scripts are being loaded correctly. The top answer here will help:

[jquery Chosen plugin in Asp.net MVC 4 does not show in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769761/jquery-chosen-plugin-in-asp-net-mvc-4-does-not-show-in-the-view)

Comment: if the js is running on a mobile (ie: refer to pageinit) you need to import [jQuery mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/download/)

Comment: Accidentally left pageinit in there when I posted. I've taken it out.

Comment: ....It works! Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7atkL8sc/1/)

Comment: Hmm strange. Works in fiddle but not in my project. It must have to do with this being a .cshtml file extension. Somehow one of these scripts must not be loaded.